# Exclude one string from bash output

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working now on a project. In this project for some reasons I need to exclude first string from the output (or file) that matches the pattern. The difficulty is in that I need to exclude just one string, just first string from the stream.
For example, if I have:

```
1 abc
2 qwerty
3 open
4 abc
5 talk
```

After some script working I should have this:

```
2 qwerty
3 open
4 abc
5 talk
```

NOTE: I don't know anything about digits before words, so I can't filter the output using knowledge about them.

I've written small script with grep, but it cuts out every string, that matches the pattern:

```
'some program' | grep -v "abc"
```

Read info about awk, sed, etc. but didn't understand if I can solve my problem.
Anything helps, Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I can. If I use the script above with the output above, I'll have the next answer: "2 qwerty 3 open 5 talk". You see, I need to have the last "4 abc" word, but I don't. And I understand why. The thing I don't understand - how to modify the script, or what kind of tool should I use.

Comment: Do you only need cut out the first occurence of a word?

Comment: @user3016814: so as nautical asks, you need to remove only the first occurrence?

Comment: Yes, seems like this, I need to delete the string where the word occurs first.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've been struggling with this problem for a while and now it' solved=)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using awk:

```
some program | awk '{ if (/abc/ && !seen) { seen = 1 } else print }'
```

Alternatively, using only filters:

```
some program | awk '!/abc/ || seen { print } /abc/ && !seen { seen = 1 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ex editor. For example to remove the first pattern from the file:

```
ex +"/abc/d" -scwq file.txt
```

From the input (replace `cat` with your program):

```
ex +"/abc/d" +%p -scq! <(cat file.txt)
```

<sup>You can also read from stdin by replacing `cat` with `/dev/stdin`.</sup>

Explanation:

- `+cmd` - execute Ex/Vim command
- `/pattern/d` - find the pattern and **d**elete,
- `%p` - print the current buffer
- `-s` - silent mode
- `-cq!` - execute quite without saving (`!`)
- `<(cmd)` - shell process substitution

Comment: Looks great, but I need to wait for a while to understand this=)

Answer (score 1):

give line numbers using sed which you want to delete

```
sed 1,2d
```

instead of 1 2 use line numbers that you want to delete

otherwise you can use

```
sed '/pattrent to match/d'
```

here we can have

```
sed '0,/abc/{//d;}'
```

Comment: see changes you can remove lines based on certain patterns

Comment: @jibe now it's much smarter solution than above.

Comment: It is still wrong. Your first solution delete line between 1 and 2 excluded. The second delete all lines matching the pattern. The third delete all lines from the start to the line matching the pattern, so if the pattern is not on the first line but on the end it will delete a lot of text.

Comment: Works great.. you're genio

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a list of commands [`{ list; }`](http://www.ing.iac.es/~docs/external/bash/bashref.html#SEC21) to `read` the first line and print the rest:

```
command | { read first_line; cat -; }
```

Simple example:

```
$ cat file
1 abc
2 qwerty
3 open
4 abc
5 talk
$ cat file | { read first_line; cat -; }
2 qwerty
3 open
4 abc
5 talk
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!/1/' file
2 qwerty
3 open
4 abc
5 talk
```

Thats all!