# Laravel5: How to disable default scheduler message if no command is ready to run

Tags: php, laravel-5, scheduler

When using the [Laravel5 scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling):

`* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

We receive the following default output if no command is ready to run:

```bash
# No scheduled commands are ready to run.
```

How to disable this default Laravel5 message? We don't want to have an output if there is no command ready to run. The best would be, when we were able to configure that message and return code on our self.

Comment: Is something like this could work?

`php artisan schedule:run | awk '{ if (/No scheduled commands are ready to run./ && !seen) { seen = 1 } else print }'`

Originally from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38716088/8068675

Comment: Or you can create your own `ScheduleRunCommand`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I've checked them once and I will try Dave S's approach soon. All provided solutions should work and are quite nice.I was sure, that one answers approach were to try change the vendor code ;).... This is very bad practise @Vinod Joshi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new command in `app/Console/Commands` similar to below, which extends the default `schedule:run` command.

It overrides the `handle` method while leaving everything else as-is to avoid having Laravel output the "No scheduled commands are ready to run." line when it didn't do anything.

By using a different name there's no need to worry about conflicts, and you can still run the original `php artisan schedule:run` command at any time if you so desire.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\ScheduleRunCommand;

class RunTasks extends ScheduleRunCommand
{
    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'run:tasks';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Custom task runner with no default output';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        parent::__construct($schedule);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        foreach ($this->schedule->dueEvents($this->laravel) as $event) {
            if (! $event->filtersPass($this->laravel)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($event->onOneServer) {
                $this->runSingleServerEvent($event);
            } else {
                $this->runEvent($event);
            }
            $this->eventsRan = true;
        }

        if (! $this->eventsRan) {
            // Laravel would output the default text here. You can remove
            // this if statement entirely if you don't want output.
            //
            // Alternatively, define some custom output with:
            // $this->info("My custom 'nothing ran' message");
        }
    }
}
```

Verify that Laravel sees your new command:

```sh
php artisan | grep run:tasks
```

Finally update your cron to run the new command:

```sh
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan run:tasks >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments I see two possibilities

You can [filter the output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38716088/8068675) by removing what you don't want

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run | awk '{ if (/No scheduled commands are ready to run./ && !seen) { seen = 1 } else print }'
```

---

Or you can override with your own command:

```
$ php artisan make:command ScheduleRunCommand
```

By making your own command *(mostly copy/past from ScheduleRunCommand)* or extending the `ScheduleRunCommand` as @dave-s proposed

And if you want to still run `php artisan schedule:run` with your new command,
you need to register it in a service provider

```
$this->app->extend('schedule.run', function () {
    return new \App\Console\Commands\ScheduleRunCommand;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code for Laravel at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/78505345f2a34b865a980cefbd103d8eb839eedf/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php#L82

```
public function handle()
{
    foreach ($this->schedule->dueEvents($this->laravel) as $event) {
        if (! $event->filtersPass($this->laravel)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($event->onOneServer) {
            $this->runSingleServerEvent($event);
        } else {
            $this->runEvent($event);
        }
        $this->eventsRan = true;
    }
    if (! $this->eventsRan) {
        $this->info('No scheduled commands are ready to run.');
    }
}
```

You see that it's handled via $this->info handler.

The info handler is defined in [Command.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/78505345f2a34b865a980cefbd103d8eb839eedf/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php#L447) Which calls the line method, which calls the [output handler](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/78505345f2a34b865a980cefbd103d8eb839eedf/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php#L462) which is defined in the [run command](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/78505345f2a34b865a980cefbd103d8eb839eedf/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php#L165)

So in essence to be able to intercept this you should be able to override the [OutputStyle](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9f313ce9bb5ad49a06ae78d33fbdd1c92a0e21f6/src/Illuminate/Console/OutputStyle.php) which is based on the [symfonystyle](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Style/SymfonyStyle.php) by binding your own output handler before running the commands in the file you call in your cron job.

The best working scenario I can think of is by using an [OutputFormatter](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5aa0967f9f0ab803ededefb040d48a0ebc7a27a6/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Formatter/OutputFormatter.php) where you simply return null when the string matches your target string.

```
 $this->output->setFormatter( new MyCatchemAllFormatter() );
```

And in the class you would define something along the lines of:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatter;

class MyCatchemAllFormatter extends OutputFormatter 
{
    public function formatAndWrap(string $message, int $width) 
    {
        if($message != 'No scheduled commands are ready to run.') {
             return parent::formatAndWrap($message, $width);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that my solution is **DIRTY** and I'll get downvotes by most of SO users, but it's quick to do without registering additional service providers, modifying classes and etc.

I've checked sources and found [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php#L81) at line *81* of `ScheduleRunCommand` which is

```
public function handle()
{
    foreach ($this->schedule->dueEvents($this->laravel) as $event) {
        if (! $event->filtersPass($this->laravel)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($event->onOneServer) {
            $this->runSingleServerEvent($event);
        } else {
            $this->runEvent($event);
        }
        $this->eventsRan = true;
    }
    if (! $this->eventsRan) { // L81
        $this->info('No scheduled commands are ready to run.'); // L82
    }
}
```

The quickest way to "cheat" with it is to copy that class to `app/Console/ScheduleRunCommand.php` and copy that file to original source path every-time when `composer dump-autoload` called.

1) Copy original file to `app/Console` folder:

```
cp vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php patch/ScheduleRunCommand.php app/Console/ScheduleRunCommand.php
```

2) add such line in `composer.json` *scripts:post-autoload-dump* section:

```
cp app/Console/ScheduleRunCommand.php vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php
```

3) modify Your message in `app/Console/ScheduleRunCommand.php` (`L82`):

```
if (! $this->eventsRan) {
    $this->info('NOTHING');
}
```

4) run: `composer dump`

and result:

[image: class patching]